# Creating Membership DB (ASPNETDB) on remote server?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, asp.net-membership

I'm building a web application which soon I'll be promoting to production. This application has a login screen, as you know I used the integrated DB for developing. Now I want to move this database to a full SQL Server 2005. I'm using the aspnet_regsql.exe to create my membership tables and stored procedures in the SQL Server 2005 but I'm getting an error:

An error occurred during the execution of the SQL file 'InstallMembership.sql'. The SQL error number is 207 and the SqlException message is: Invalid column name 'FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart'.

I google this for half of the day already and I can't seem to fine what's wrong, does anybody have ANY ideas on what am I doing wrong here? Any help will be really appreciate it.

Comment: Does `dbo.aspnet_Membership` table exist? Does it have a column of that name?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to deploy a brand new database to a remote server is to just [publish the database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907585%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) from within Visual Studio. Once you do that you have the scheme and data all in one script. You then access your server either via a local SQL manager connection or a remote manager and run the script on your remote database.

The site [4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20210306172456/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050907-1.aspx) has a nice little walk through with graphics which describe how to accomplish the publishing of your local database to your hosted one.

Good luck, and hope this helps you out some.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the *.sql script file and see where that column reference is.  Then you'll be able to see what exactly the script is doing to cause this error.  My guess would be that it is getting caught up on referential integrity.  If it is trying to create a foreign key constraint that that table/column does not exist then you'll see that error.

But back to the original question at hand.  You don't need to recreate your whole database.  That script file is to lay down the Membership for an empty database.  If you have a working dev database you can just back it up and restore it to a production instance.  No need to rebuild the membership database objects.